# How to call a Database function using spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to call a database function from spring boot application which will return a decrypted value.

Is it possible to call database functions using spring data jpa? 
If possible how?

If not possible using spring data jpa, Is there any alternatives to call functions from spring boot?

Here is my function

```
IF OBJECT_ID('fn_MASK_CARD') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION fn_MASK_CARD
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_MASK_CARD (
    @CARD_NUMBER  VARCHAR(19)
    )
   RETURNS VARCHAR(19)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@CARD_NUMBER,1,6)+REPLICATE('#',LEN(@CARD_NUMBER)-10)+
                                                        SUBSTRING(@CARD_NUMBER,LEN(@CARD_NUMBER)-3,LEN(@CARD_NUMBER));
END
GO
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read how to ask a question here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You could just simply use `@Query` for that

Comment: Look up JPA custom queries. It is very possible yes.

Comment: Thank you @benjaminc . Can u provide me any examples for the same?

Comment: @benjaminc I want to call the above function using spring data jpa? Since i don't have any entity related to that function how can i create an interface extending jpaRepository

Comment: @MatMat any example?

Comment: But you have already existing repositories, right? Otherwise you wouldn't use Spring Data. So you probably have a repository where you would use that number. So you can add the method there. But why don't you just create that function in Java code, and call that? This is quite easy, and i see no reason why you would want to do a database call for such a simple thing.

Comment: @dunni yeah, its simple, but i am working on an existing application. So its not possible to add java code at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally found the answer, just added the below code in my repository and it worked!

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT DBO.fn_MASK_CARD(:text)")
String callMaskCard(@Param("text") String text);
```

Comment: for me this worked @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT CAST(gen_random_uuid as varchar) from gen_random_uuid") I had to cast the output otherwise it was throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me. Try adding the below code into your repository.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT fn_MASK_CARD(:card_num) FROM DUAL")
String maskCard(@Param("card_num") String card_num);
```

Answer (score 1):

`nativeQuery = true` it is a precondition in Spring JPA to call the database functions.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT your_function()", nativeQuery = true)
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

you call DB function from a DAO  as

`{? = call <package_name>.<>Function_Name(<parameter >)}`

eg

```
{? = call mypackage.myfunction(?)}
```