# Spring JPA @Query with JPQL and MySQL FUNCTION CONVERT(col USING charset)

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-el

I have two MySQL tables with different charset UTF8(table_a) and latin1(table_b) and I would like translate the following native query to JPQL (JPA 2.1):

```
SELECT a.* FROM table_a a, table_b b WHERE CONVERT(a.id USING latin1) = b.a_id;
```

I tried the next expressions but are wrong:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM tableA a, tableB WHERE FUNCTION('CONVERT', a.id USING latin) = b.aId")

@Query("SELECT a FROM tableA a, tableB WHERE FUNCTION('CONVERT', 'a.id USING latin') = b.aId")

@Query("SELECT a FROM tableA a, tableB WHERE FUNCTION('CONVERT', a.id, 'USING latin') = b.aId")

@Query("SELECT a FROM tableA a, tableB WHERE FUNCTION('CONVERT', a.id 'USING latin') = b.aId")
```

Is there a way to use MySQL CONVERT function with JPQL?

Comment: I don't think that JPQL allows for the `FUNCTION` or `CONVERT` keywords, but you could add `nativeQuery = true` to your `@Query` in order to use native MySQL functions.
`@Query("SELECT a FROM tableA a, tableB WHERE FUNCTION('CONVERT', a.id USING latin) = b.aId", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: I just read https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-calling-database-functions.html

Comment: If you are using vanilla JPQL and Hibernate, the link you shared would work. However, if you are using SpringData, adding `nativeQuery = true` will solve the problem.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196604/12794752).  By using `nativeQuery`, you would use your base SQL query.

Comment: I appreciate your time but I need to use JPQL to simplify the field mapping. TableA is a very complex POJO and the example I gave was a great simplification of the real query. I will try with Criteria.

Comment: The problem actually is how to use FUNCTION in JPQL with special parameters like CHAR, USING, INTERVAL...etc

Comment: Then why not do as the [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-calling-database-functions.html) you shared suggests? Make a separate repository that isn't set up with SpringData in order to use more vanilla JPQL, then use the SpringData `@Query` annotation in the main repository?

Comment: @darkmnemic It works fine with nativeQuery=true. Thank you.